# How to securely retrieve API credentials in Android?

Tags: android, api, rest, security, credentials

My current process to secure iOS app connected to web service is the following.

1. iOS Client credentials (public id + secret) to access web service are stored into CloudKit public database **(available only for my app)**
2. At first launch, my app is securely retrieving credentials from CloudKit
3. On change from CloudKit, my app is automatically notified and can update stored credentials
4. Credentials are securely stored in keychain.

Like this, there is **no credentials on my source code**.

With Android, I can securely store credentials once retrieved. But how can I **retrieve API credentials without storing them in my source code**?

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Do you mean the credentials you receive from CloudKit, or the credentials to access CloudKit (if any)? Are these API credentials per-user/install, or shared between all installations?

Comment: @F.StephenQ I mean the credentials I receive from CloudKit, stored in public database as standard records, and shared between all installations.